# Bootstrap5 modal not displaying in React.js after clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap5 to React. I successfully installed the bootstrap5 in React. Now I have to show the modal on my page so I added a button and modal code on my page.

Below is the code I am using for the modal. Now I click on the button then nothing is working. I am not getting my modal.

What is the issue here?

```
import React from "react";

function addEmployee(){
    return(
<div className="addEmployee">
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Add Employee</button>

<div className="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div className="modal-dialog">
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <h5 className="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>

    )
}
export default addEmployee;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you'd use `react-bootstrap` its a lot easier and the javascript has been done for  you

> React-Bootstrap replaces the Bootstrap JavaScript

Each component has been built from scratch as a  React component, without unneeded dependencies like jQuery.

To get started just install the package `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

look at this example

```
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

Gaurav Singhal's blog @ [PluralSight](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-trigger-modal-for-react-bootstrap)

> You must use controlled components that use the internal state to set
> the values and change the behavior of a component. Libraries like
> jQuery do direct DOM manipulation, whereas React components use
> Virtual DOM to modify the actual DOM on the browser. Using jQuery to
> change your component's behavior is possible. Still, it will lead to
> unexpected results and make it difficult to debug. React Bootstrap
> implements each component in pure React, so you don't have to worry
> about Bootstrap's dependency on jQuery

to check out their (react-bootstrap) documentation page ,here is the link you can follow/go to [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

Comment: I already installed the bootstrap5. Do I need to uninstall that?

Comment: No ,just run npm install react-bootstrap ,React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, it doesn't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components. so you have import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; to your index.js file

Comment: I got an error   Line 5:27:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "addEmployee" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Ok. So I added import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"; and function name in capital letter. and solved my issues

Comment: It's really easy to implements a `react-bootstrap`  based navigation, but when custom navigations design comes from UI/UX designer it is also tough to implement in react project specifically functionality! any idea?

Answer (score 25):

**Bootstrap 5 no longer depends on jQuery** so you don't need a 3rd party library library like `react-bootstrap` to use Bootstrap in React. For example you can use the `data-bs-` attributes in the markup, ***or*** create a functional component for the Bootstrap modal with methods to show/hide the modal...

```
function ModalExample() {
    const modalRef = useRef()
    
    const showModal = () => {
        const modalEle = modalRef.current
        const bsModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalEle, {
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        })
        bsModal.show()
    }
    
    const hideModal = () => {
        const modalEle = modalRef.current
        const bsModal= bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modalEle)
        bsModal.hide()
    }
    
    return(
        <div className="addEmployee">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={showModal}>Add Employee</button>
            <div className="modal fade" ref={modalRef} tabIndex="-1" >
             <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                    <h5 className="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" className="btn-close" onClick={hideModal} aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    ...
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={hideModal}>Close</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Demo of both methods](https://codeply.com/p/FLqwWV6Oan)

Comment: works like a charm thanks. I find this solution more elegant than relying on another library.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm.